# twitter profile followers count using userid

Tags: php, cakephp, twitter

I need to get the twitter profile followers count.

The thing is that I don't get the token value here, but I do have the twitter account userid.

Can we get the number of followers based on this basic data..?

Answer (score 0):

Either way you will need the token, since it is required to perform authentication for all requests to the Twitter API. But to get that token, it's not complicated using **[Application-only authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth)**.

First of all, you will need create a **[Twitter App](https://apps.twitter.com/)** to get **api key** and **api secret**.

Now, just get the bearer token:

```
$encoded_consumer_key = urlencode(CONSUMER_KEY);
$encoded_consumer_secret = urlencode(CONSUMER_SECRET);
$bearer_token = $encoded_consumer_key.':'.$encoded_consumer_secret;
$base64_consumer_key = base64_encode($bearer_token);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
$headers = array(
        "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1",
        "Host: api.twitter.com",
        "User-Agent: Twitter Application-only OAuth App",
        "Authorization: Basic ".$base64_consumer_key,
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        "Content-Length: 29"
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
$header = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$output = explode("\n", $response);
$bearer_token = '';
foreach($output as $line) {
    if ($line !== false) {
        $bearer_token = $line;
    }
}
$bearer_token = json_decode($bearer_token);
$bearer_token = $bearer_token->{'access_token'};
```

Now that you have the **bearer token**, you can make a [lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup) on the user with *user_id*:

```
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json";
$formed_url = '?user_id='.$user_id;
$headers = array(
        "GET /1.1/users/lookup.json".$formed_url." HTTP/1.1",
        "Host: api.twitter.com",
        "User-Agent: Twitter Application-only OAuth App",
        "Authorization: Bearer ".$bearer_token."",
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url.$formed_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Then in **$response** (it's *json*) you have everything you need, including **followers_count**.